# Primefaces looks different on IE - CSS Problems

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, primefaces

i have some problems with deploying in netbeans.

first of all i made a design in xhtml and css. everything was fine.

then i includes faces components and primefaces. primefaces looks great in firefox 8 but in internet explorer 9 it's very displaced. can anyone explain me why this happens?

here is my xhtml and css:
http://www.file-upload.net/download-4117990/web.rar.html

http://jsfiddle.net/DSEPM/

sorry for uploading, i couldn't insert code here

Comment: Can you upload to something like [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: If you switch browser mode in ie9 to ie8 (via F12 developer tools). Does it get better?

Comment: Hrmm well that's not rendering properly because of your relative images and (I think*) server-side code (?), do you have a live version somewhere? It's hard to debug when we can't actually see how it's rendering for you.

Comment: switching browser mode to ie8 didn't make it better.

i have no live version, here are screenshots of ie9 (displaced) and firefox (working)
[link](http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/lq7d4dxv/ie9.jpg) IE9 and [link](http://img7.imagebanana.com/img/ieiszmog/ff8.jpg) ff

Comment: Can you verify if all your resources files get loaded or if some of the requests fail? How are your elements aligned, css or table?

Comment: my elements are aligned in my css file.. the css file gets loaded because backgroundcolor and div positions are correct.
i'm just wondering why ie9 don't centered the outerFrame div and don't loaded the css3 components like box-shadow.
another thing is the displaced primeface components.. in every other browser it's correct

Comment: i am such an idiot.. my ie had a wrong configuration

Answer (score 1):

add `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the top of your template page